# Spring 5 and reactive programming

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I’ve noticed that Spring framework introduced reactive stack in spring 5.0 release which is build on [project reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) and [reactive stream specification](https://www.reactive-streams.org/). I’m curious to know, if anybody has this information, why they choose project reactor when [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) seems to be a better choice (widely used, great community, longer history that usually means fewer bugs, implement reactive streams specification, etc.)

Comment: Essentially all of the reactive APIs are built on reactivestreams. It's a very small package that simply standardizes how to use streams to connect a publisher with a subscriber. 
Agree with @MichaelBerry's - namely, the most essential difference is the Java version targeted. Next, although reactor can be used without Spring, it integrates very well with Spring. If you are using Spring, it makes sense to opt for the provided API, since it will continue to be supported, likely leading to better performance. Also, since Reactor is backed by Pivotal, it has a very promising future.

Comment: https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2019/02/rxjava-vs-reactor.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reactor has been going for a few years now - it's not as young a project as you make it sound. It also conforms to the reactive streams spec AFAIK, so there's no difference there.

That being said, there's likely both political and technical reasons why Reactor was used here.

Politically, Spring and Reactor are both Pivotal projects - RxJava is not.

Technically however, RxJava's big advantage, and disadvantage, depending on how you look at it, is that it supports older versions than Java 8. That's great if you want to target Java 6, but if you're only targeting Java 8 anyway it comes with some overhead & duplication (since it means RxJava can't use any of the new inbuilt Java 8 classes, such as `Optional`, `Function`, etc.).

Reactor on the other hand is Java 8+ only, so it can make full use of the new Java 8 native classes. Since Spring 5.0 is also Java 8+ only, that means Reactor has the edge in this regard.